# How to prevent the call to a property or method on an any variable

Tags: node.js, typescript, properties, any

after some research, I couldn't find an answer to this problem :

In a NodeJs project with typescript, if I have an any variable, is there a way to prevent the call to an unidentified property or method from this variable either using typescript compilation or eslint or something else ?

Here is an exemple:

```
let test: any;

console.log( test.unknownProperty ); // Should not pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no TypeScript compiler setting to do this, since the whole point of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is to turn off type checking and allow all sorts of potentially unsafe operations.  TypeScript's viewpoint is that you shouldn't use `any` in this circumstance.

Fortunately for your use case, there is [a `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access` ESLint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-member-access/) which behaves this way:

> This rule disallows member access on any variable that is typed as `any`.

Let's test it out:

```
let test: any;

console.log(test.unknownProperty); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Unsafe member access .unknownProperty on an `any` value.
```

Looks good.

[TypeScript ESLint Playground link](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.9.3&sourceType=module&code=DYUwLgBGIM5gXBAhgOwJ4G4CwAoXBjAexRkNADphCBzACmjnIFcUBrFQgdxQAUAnQgAcQfMGgCUGCAHppEEQL4BCXLIgBaTVvUA+CAD9DR4yZOq5AVRJIAZiAgBbEA4BGI5PnywYEZmw7c-EIiYhDEyCgQAAaoaFEQAG5IwEwg5BC4QA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tieQEMAZoloBbRCIBGiaLT5kyKVBkjToHaJHDYAviG1A&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eFYDAruuGAL4g9A)